# Rails has_many :through, null belongs_to, multiple belongs_to and deletion of belongs_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, cancan

I would like to know if I am on the right track and if rails allows this sort of thing.

`User` has one `Role` in a `Network`. i.e. "Jim" is a "History Teacher" at a "School".

A `Role` has both a position (power) and a name (label). "Jim" is a "History Teacher" (label) but has the authority of a member or admin, or supervisor, or whatever (power).

Depending on that `Role` a `User` can see all `Events` in the `Network` whether or not he/she created them. i.e. "Jim" can see "Nancy's" "Recess Plan" if "Jim" is a "Principal" (admin) but not if "Jim" is a "History Teacher" (member).

A `User` creates an `Event` as a `Role` within a `Network`. i.e. "Jim" creates "Lesson Plan" as "History Teacher" at "School."

`Event` is forever connected to that specific `Network` and currently to that `Role`.

I want that `Event` to persist if a `User` replaces another `User` in that `Role`, and the new `User` can access that `Event`. i.e. "Tom" replaces "Jim" as the "History Teacher" and can modify "Lesson Plan" because he is the "History Teacher". "Jim" can no longer access "Lesson Plan."

But I also want an `Event` to persist if there is no `User` attached to a `Role`. i.e. "Tom" is fired and there is no current replacement, an admin can still see "Lesson Plan".

Finally, if that `Role` is deleted, the `Event` still exists as connected to that `Network` without a `Role`.

The models are below, I am using CanCan for authorization, and these are my questions:

1. Can a role be missing a `User`, or would I need to create some generic "None" `User` or "Everyone" `User`? And can `Event` be missing a `Role`? (Can belongs_to be null?)
2. Is it good/bad design to connect an `Event` to both a `Role` and a `Network`? Is there a better way to do this?
3. If a `User` can see more events depending on his/her `Role` do they have many `Events` through the `Network` or their `Role`? I am thinking through `Network` and the Ability.rb would limit it.

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
  has_many :networks, :through => :roles

  has_many :events, :through => :network
  # I would use CanCan to determine the authorization of
  # what network events they can see based on their role?
end
```

Network.rb

```
class Network < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
  has_many :users, :through => :roles

  has_many :events
  # it shouldn't have this through roles right?
  # because a role can be deleted
end
```

Role.rb

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user     #CAN THIS BE NULL?
  belongs_to :network
end
```

Event.rb

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :role      #Can this be null?

  belongs to :network
  # Does it belong to the network through the role,
  # or can it belong on its own, in case the role is deleted?

  # belongs_to :user, :through => :roles
  # Is this necessary if I am using CanCan
  # to determine if a User can reach the event?

end
```

Ability.rb

```
if user  
  user.roles.each do |role|
    can :manage, Event, :role_id => role.id
    if role.position == "admin" || role.position == "manager"
      can :manage, Event, :network_id => role.network_id
    elseif role.position == "supervisor"
      can :read, Event, :network_id => role.network_id
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: your question is really heavy - you may get a better response by splitting it up into smaller problems that are easier to explain

Comment: Thanks, will do. I kept thinking how to do that and wasn't sure but ill give it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your associations are fine, and you can have null `belongs_to` fields.  Rails does not create foreign-key constraints on the database by default.  As far as the CanCan setup goes, I would do something like:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    #Adding can rules do not override prior rules, but instead are logically or'ed.
    #See: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Ability-Precedence

    #Anything that you can pass to a hash of conditions in Active Record will work here.
    #The only exception is working with model ids. 
    #You can't pass in the model objects directly, you must pass in the ids.
    #can :manage, Project, :group => { :id => user.group_ids }
    #See https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities

    can :read, Event, network: {id: user.supervises_network_ids} 
    can :manage, Event, role: {id: user.role_ids}
    can :manage, Event, network: {id: user.manages_network_ids + user.admins_network_ids}
  end
end
```

Where you have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  def manages_network_ids
    @manages_network_ids ||= roles.manager.collect &:network_id
  end

  def admins_network_ids
    @admins_network_ids ||= roles.admin.collect &:network_id
  end

  def supervises_network_ids
    @supervises_network_ids ||= roles.supervisor.collect &:network_id
  end
  #...
end
```

And on Role you have:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  scope :manager, where(position: "manager")
  scope :admin, where(position: "admin")
  scope :supervisor, where(position: "supervisor")
  #...
end
```

This allows your Event to have a null `role_id`, since you will allow any admins (or managers) on a network to manage all events, constrained by `network_id`.  Also, if you reassign the role to a new user, the old user will no longer be able to manage the event, and the new one will.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question `belongs_to` can technically be `nil`. You would have to put a validation (`validates_presence_of`) to avoid that.

**I don't know CanCan** but, on the conceptual level, I would not have written so many associations just to be able to access the data. A Rails association is far more than a data reader and I am not sure that you need it every cases here.

For instance, User#events could be replaced by:

```
def events
  roles.includes(:events).map(&:events).flatten
end
```

Or

```
def events
  Event.where(:role_id => roles.map(&:id))
end
```

Or

```
def events
  Event.joins(:role).where(:role => {:user_id => id})
end
```

You can add some memoization if you call this method more than once.
In fact, if you call it just once, you barely need a method for that.

About associating an event both to a role and a network, I would be carefull because you may have consistency issue (you have to ensure that `event.role.network == event.network`). Another way is to have, for each network, a default role that can not been destroyed. But it may be not much simpler.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the built-in associations?  Using `has_many through:` gets you more than just an accessor.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure of there was actually an association between user and events. The point was that a user can access an event either because their role was directly attached to an event or because their access rights in a network are high enough to let them see all of a network's events. Does that change the way I would use that method? Can Can would basically just be used to check whether to display all events, or just personal ones. And it would prevent access. It's such a useful gem, but it is confusing me regarding associations.

Comment: @SeanHill I am not a Rails expert but making a model architecture more complex only to avoid a one line arel query seems a bit overkill to me. The requested feature sounds like a scope, not a true association. At least, I would specifically document these associations as convenient accessors. Beyond that, if CanCan requests this, or if we need more than just reading data, that's another story.

Comment: Okay, so you've arbitrarily restricted your model for no gain, in my opinion.  You have now lost the ability to eager load Events, without doing extra work.  Using `has_many :events through: roles`, I can do `User.include(:events)`, and have it automatically build the join query.