# CanCan vs. Rails Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, cancan

I think I have gone and confused myself over the power of CanCan.

I asked a longer question here - [Rails has_many :through, null belongs_to, multiple belongs_to and deletion of belongs_to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717456/rails-has-many-through-null-belongs-to-multiple-belongs-to-and-deletion-of-be). But at the advice of one of the members, I simplified my question with what I think is my ultimately question.

In short, a `User` has a `Role` in a `Network`. A `User` can also create `Events`, however, what `Events` they can see/edit are all based on that `Role`. If a `User` loses their `Role` they no longer have access to an `Event`.

Additionally, if the `User` and/or `Role` that created the `Event` is removed, the `Event` will still exists in the `Network` and be visible to all `Users` with a high enough authority (admin, manager, etc.) in their `Role`.

I can use CanCan to determine if a `User` has access to an `Event` by testing their `Role`. That part is working fine.

But more conceptually, if I am using CanCan to control both the access to the controller actions for `Events` as well as whether or not the `Event` is even displayed in the view based on `can :read`, is there a need for an rails `has_many :through` association between `Users` and `Events`? Since technically the `User` is only connected to the `Event` through a `Role` in a `Network`, can I just leave it to CanCan to control access, or do I need an association. Would it be good to have a method like:

```
def events
  ... # info for grabbing all events user has access to?
end
```

Or is that also unnecessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to use the has_many :through

Take a look at: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/defining-abilities

You can assign different roles for the users and check permissions using what they say in the wiki I just posted

Comment: So then there is no formal association between User and Events? And that is acceptable/good rails practice?

Comment: what if you do a normal association like User has_many :events? And restrict that relation on CanCan? would that work for you or do you need something more specific?