# Add groups to CanCan in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I am using Devise and CanCan. I would like to create groups of users so they will be in a group and be able to have a group leader. The group leader can add / edit / delete users only from that group.

I have followed http://edapx.com/2012/04/18/authorization-and-user-management-in-rails/ am not sure how to create groups now. Is it possible to do this in CanCan?

Comment: Are you talking about group owners changing group members only, or these groups are also privilege groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13747645/367611

Basically, you'll have something like this:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  initialize(user)
    can :manage, User, groups: {id: user.led_group_ids}
    can :manage, Group, id: user.led_group_ids
  end
end
```

Then in your User model, something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :groups

  def led_groups
    @led_groups ||= groups.where(leader: true)
  end

  def led_group_ids
    @led_group_ids ||= led_groups.collect(&:id)
  end
end
```